# How to add a view that overlaps a tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a tutorial in my iOS application and I have a tableview with a drawer.

For the first time that the user enters in this screen, a tutorial overlaps the screen first, and disappears after the user taps OK.

Like this

[image]

I've tried this tutorial:
http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/creating-custom-user-interface-files-with-xib-in-xcode-6-and-swift/ 
in which I can use in a UIView but not in a tableview.

I hope someone can give me a hint on how to do it or what to use.

Comment: We won't write the app for you. What have you tried in iOS coding ?

Comment: I've tried using addSubview, but I dont know how to use it in a tableview

Comment: Please show your codes in your question. Edit it.

Comment: Do you want to implement slidingMenu ?

Comment: @HitendraHckr I already implemented the sliding menu.. what i want to do there is to add an overlay or overlap another view to make a tutorial for first time users.

Comment: Please Check my answer for your requirements.

Comment: @black1011 I think the tuotorial that comes in most of the apps is just an image are you want to show some image or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a temporary solution to my problem.

1. I made an image like this:

[image]

2. Create a ViewController and put the image, then add label and button (edit cross dissolve as transition type).
3. Show this view controller for first time users and go to the next view controller if the button is clicked which is the real view controller(the one that has table view and sliding menu)

The problem here is I need to have different images for different screen size if I really want that the user wont notice the tableview spacing, but it still looks fine.

Comment: You can convert images to different sizes as according to different device screen size programmatically.

Comment: @Arpit, yes you can convert the image to different sizes but the spacing of the tableview of the enlarged/reduced image would be larger/smaller compared to the spacing of a real tableview in the device.

Comment: Can you provide me that image?

Comment: The image at the top is the one I'm using, you can download that one.. its a screenshot of iphone5s.

Comment: I made a demo project, see if it helps: [AImageSize](https://github.com/ArpitOnTheWay/AImageResize)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this for tutorial view Controller** 
https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough

In your FirstView controller, 
**1)** Create instance of tutorial ViewController
**2)** Present that Tutorial ViewController

There is a close button delegate method in BWWalkthrough, i.e. `walkthroughCloseButtonPressed()` in this method dismiss your tutorial viewController.